# Configure both ADD (not B2C) and Azure B2C in a single Angular app with msal without page reload

Tags: angular, azure, authentication

We have a requirement where on login screen user has to be enabled with both options(using separate buttons) for Azure B2c and B2E which would have different configurations to be integrated in Angular application , how can we achieve this effectively without Application reload?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's more sort of changing msal configuration dynamically (clientId, Authority) depending on button click and page reload.